# onCommand.addListener not working in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a chrome extension, only, I am facing a problem since onCommand.addListener is not working in my `background.js` file. My `manifest.json` file looks like this:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Copy",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js"
  },

  "commands": {
    "run-foo": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
      },
      "description": "Run \"foo\" on the current page."
    },
    "_execute_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y",
        "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+J"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my `background.js` file in the `js` folder looks like this:

```js
console.log('test');

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command){
    if(command === 'run-foo'){
      sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});

      console.log('copié !!!');
      let copieText = 'je suis le texte copié';
    }
});

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  console.log('onCommand event received for message: ', command);
});
```

But my console only returns the test, even if I press Ctrl-C several times.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1) sendResponse is only defined inside chrome.runtime.onMessage listener but you have two onCommand listeners. 2) `window` is not available in a MV3 service worker, you need to use it inside the content script. 3) Don't use the `commands` API at all, instead use a content script to listen to `copy` event, there are lot of examples.

Comment: Do you have an example of what should be put inside the `background.js` or `script.js` file to detect a user copy ?